# Why are in-range narrowed long values not implicitly converted?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, constants, literals

When we declare a `static final`, the Java compiler (or pre-compiler?) seems smart enough to detect out-of-range numbers:

```
public class Test {
    // setup variables:
    public static final int i_max_byte = 127;
    public static final int i_max_byte_add1 = 128;
    public static final int i_max_short = 32767;
    public static final int i_max_short_add1 = 32768;
    public static final int i_max_char = 65535;
    public static final int i_max_char_add1 = 65536;
    public static final char c_max_byte = 127;
    public static final char c_max_byte_add1 = 128;
    public static final char c_max_short = 32767;
    public static final char c_max_short_add1 = 32768;
    public static final short s_min_char = 0;
    public static final short s_min_char_sub1 = -1;
    public static final short s_max_byte = 127;
    public static final short s_max_byte_add1 = 128;

    // all these are OK:
    public static final byte b1 = i_max_byte;
    public static final byte b2 = s_max_byte;
    public static final byte b3 = c_max_byte;
    public static final byte b4 = (short) i_max_byte;
    public static final byte b5 = (char) i_max_byte;
    public static final char c1 = i_max_char;
    public static final char c2 = s_min_char;
    public static final short s1 = i_max_short;
    public static final short s2 = c_max_short;

    // pre-compiler complains "type-mismatch":
    public static final byte _b1 = i_max_byte_add1;
    public static final byte _b2 = s_max_byte_add1;
    public static final byte _b3 = c_max_byte_add1;
    public static final byte _b4 = (short) i_max_byte_add1;
    public static final byte _b5 = (char) i_max_byte_add1;
    public static final char _c1 = i_max_char_add1;
    public static final char _c2 = s_min_char_min_us1;
    public static final short _s1 = i_max_short_add1;
    public static final short _s2 = c_max_short_add1;
}
```

The code above proves that for `int`, `short`, and `char` values, the compiler only complains when the value is out-of-range for the type of the assigned variable.

However for `long` values, the compiler complains even when the numbers are within range:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static final long l_max_byte = 127;
    public static final long l_max_byte_add1 = 128;
    public static final long l_max_char = 32767;
    public static final long l_max_char_add1 = 32768;
    public static final long l_max_short = 65535;
    public static final long l_max_short_add1 = 65536;
    public static final long l_max_int = 2147483647;
    public static final long l_max_int_add1 = 2147483648L;

    // "type-mismatch" for all:
    public static final byte b1 = l_max_byte;
    public static final byte b2 = l_max_byte_add1;
    public static final char c1 = l_max_char;
    public static final char c2 = l_max_char_add1;
    public static final short s1 = l_max_short;
    public static final short s2 = l_max_short_add1;
    public static final int i1 = l_max_int;
    public static final int i2 = l_max_int_add1;
}
```

Why is the compiler only smart at range-detection for  `int`, `short`, and `char` values?

Why doesn't the compiler do range-detection for `long` values?

Comment: The compiles does this because of older java design and only in limited ranges (-128 - 127). Widening just works find though.

Comment: @Hannes, Yea widening is fine (since it's well, always within-range). It's the narrowing part that's odd. Somehow range-detection is activated only when the value being narrowed is of type `int`, `short`, or `char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>The answer may not be satisfactory, but...</sub>

The [Java Language Specification, Section 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), says:

> Assignment contexts allow the value of an expression to be assigned (§15.26) to a variable; the type of the expression must be converted to the type of the variable.
>
> ...
>
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

For the cases that compile fine, the constant expression is always of type `short`, `char`, or `int`, and the value is representable in the target type. For the `long` type, such a conversion is simply not allowed according to the specification.

---

The answer may not be satisfactory, because the next obvious question is:

> *Why did they write the specification like that?*

This may partially be answered by the example that is also given in the linked section of the JLS: This implicit conversion is most likely mainly intended for the case that you want to write a declaration like

```
byte b = 42;
```

because otherwise, you would have to cast the `int` value 42 to byte like in

```
byte b = (byte)42;
```

The case that you want to initialize a `byte` from a `long` value is just not so common in this sense.